# Need to extract xsi:type attribute value using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, sax

I want to extract the xsi:type attribute value from the XML as below

```
<interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="SerialInterface">
```

I want to extract the xsi:type attribute value i.e. *SerialInterface* here.

I was trying to use `node.getAttributeValue` but that's not exactly working

Answer (score 0):

I would use StAX.

```
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(s));
    xr.next();
    String type = xr.getAttributeValue(0);
```

Note that I used attribute index 0. This is because XML parser does not return xmlns:xsi attr.

This is SAX based version

```
    String s = "<interface xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"SerialInterface\" />";
    final StringBuilder type = new StringBuilder();
    SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
            .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()), new DefaultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                        Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
                    if (type.length() == 0) {
                        type.append(attrs.getValue("xsi:type"));
                    }
                }
            });
    System.out.println(type);
```

output

```
SerialInterface
```

Comment: I have to use SAX and I have an "Element" type say node. Can I use something like node.getAttributeValue() to fetch that?

Comment: Are you sure you need SAX not DOM?

Comment: yes, the rest part is done with SAX. So can not change that now.